# Are any two uncountable sets similar to each other?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Two sets $A$ and $B$ are called similar $\iff$ thee exists a one to one function $F$ whose domain is the set $A$ and whose range is the set $B$.

We know that two countably infinite sets should be similar to each other but what about uncountable sets?

**Attempt:** Let $a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots$ be elements in $A$ and $b_1,b_2,b_3,\cdots$ in $B$.

Then, can we say that this mapping : $a_1 \rightarrow b_1, a_2 \rightarrow b_2, \cdots$ is a one one onto correspondence between $A$ and $B$?  I am a little confused.

> **EDIT:** My query actually arose from this problem : If $B$ is uncountable and $A$ is uncountable, then we need to prove that $B$ is similar to $B-A$. I proved that $B-A$ is uncountable and $B$ is already uncountable. Now, I should prove that $B$ and $B-A$ are similar. Could you please give me a hint?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There are many uncountable cardinals. If $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal, then $2^\kappa$ is an uncountable cardinal with $2^\kappa > \kappa$. (It's a theorem by Cantor that for all cardinals $\kappa$ one has $\kappa < 2^\kappa$.)

Comment: Well, any two countable sets are similar because "countable" refers to only one cardinality, and similarity is the definition of being equinumerous. But Cantor's theorem shows you that there's always a properly bigger set if you can form the powerset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uncountable just means not countable. Much like infinite means not finite, and there are many different ways to be not finite, there are different ways to be uncountable.

More specifically $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ is uncountable, and by Cantor's theorem it is not similar to $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thank you . My query actually arose from this problem : If $B$ is uncountable and $A$ is uncountable, then we need to prove that $B$ is similar to $B-A$. I proved that $B-A$ is uncountable and $B$ is already uncountable. Now, I should prove that $B$ and $B-A$ are similar. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: edited my comment ..

Comment: @VHP: Is $A \subseteq B$ in your problem?

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Nope. Its not in my problem

Comment: @VHP: Is $A$ countable maybe? Otherwise it's not really true.

Comment: @AsafKaragila yeah, the problem has two parts . One is the case when $B$ is uncountable and $A$ is uncountable and the other case is when $B$ is uncountable and $A$ is countable. The problem asks whether $B \sim (B-A)$ in each case.

Comment: @AsafKaragila An Edit please : I was able to prove that when $A$ is countable and $B$ is uncountable, then $B-A$ is uncountable. How do I proceed ahead?

Comment: @VHP: Is it maybe "prove or give a counterexample"?

Comment: As for the countable case, this was asked several times before on the site.

Comment: @AsafKaragila yes. The question statement is : Can you prove that when : (i) $A$ is countable and $B$ is uncountable, $(B-A) \sim B$ (ii) $A$ is uncountable and $B$ is uncountable, $(B-A) \sim B$.

$\\$ So I think it's more of an open question and asks actually to prove or disprove. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to move much forward than in the above steps in both cases

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was able to come across some questions of this type. But, they were asking this : Uncountable set minus a countable set is uncountable. I was able to prove this but not able to move forward in proving that Uncountable set minus a countable set is similar to the uncountable set.

Comment: $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, in fact proven by [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem), is not uncountable.

Comment: @bb_823: So... You're saying that $\cal P(\Bbb R)$ is in fact countable? By Cantor's theorem? I'm confused.

Comment: @AsafKaragila it seems like I have made a mistake. I thought uncountable meant that a set has a cardinality equal to that of $\mathbb{R}$, but apparently not. Though the question does seem a bit misleading. It looks to me by the question that the OP was talking about cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ when saying uncountable, since the statement does ask to prove, rather than to check if it is correct. But anyways, my bad.

Comment: @bb_823: It is literally the first sentence of my answer. Uncountable just means not countable.